# JavaScript check value

Tags: javascript

```
var it = doc.findItem('toy_total');
it.value = parseFloat(total_due) + parseFloat(sales_tax);
fixMoney(it);
```

I am trying to add total_due + sales_tax which i can do without any issues, but sometimes there is no sales tax and when that comes up i get an NaN. I am not sure how to check for null value can someone show how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
it.value = (+total_due) + (+sales_tax);
```

`parseFloat("")` returns NaN, `+""` returns 0;

Answer (score 1):

```
var it = doc.findItem('toy_total');
if(total_due && sales_tax){
  it.value = parseFloat(total_due) + parseFloat(sales_tax);
  fixMoney(it);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [IsNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function, should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
it.value = parseFloat(total_due || 0) + parseFloat(sales_tax || 0);
```